# Error and warning highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, warning, error

I use Emacs to write LISP and Python code. I have tried NetBeans and Eclipse before, which had the advantage of parsing the buffer and highlighting problems, e.g. if one function or symbol is not defined.

Is such syntax highlighting of errors and warnings possible in Emacs?

Comment: [elpy](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for python.

Comment: I couldn't install ElPy from the repo and asked about it here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60614/unable-to-install-elpy-eval-buffer-cannot-open-load-file-no-such-file-or-dir