# Unable to install ElPy: "eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, s"

Tags: syntax-highlighting, elpy

I followed [the instructions](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to install ElPy from source: I cloned the repo to `~/code/elpy` and added these to the Emacs initialization file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/code/elpy")
(load "elpy")
(load "elpy-rpc")
(load "elpy-shell")
(load "elpy-profile")
(load "elpy-refactor")
(load "elpy-django")
```

And I get this error in `*Messages*`:

```
Loading ~/code/elpy/elpy.el (source)...
eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, s
```

with no more details.

How can I install ElPy on Emacs 27.1 (9.0) and macOS 10.14.6?

Comment: That cryptic `s` is the name of a library, [s.el](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) that (I guess) elpy depends on. You might also want to install the same author's [dash.el](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) library which many packages depend on (the cryptic part there is that every name begins with a dash: `-map`, `-copy`, `-filter` etc. etc.)

Comment: That was correct `M-x install-package s` fixed this issue. I got a similar warning about `pyvenv` and so [filed an issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1836).